# Updating a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

Hey guys, I have an ASP.NET GridView bound to a DataView that contains a DataTable. I'm not using a DataAdapter.

I want to update a row in my DataTable, so I do this:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    DataView dv = (DataView)Session["My_DataTable"];
    DataTable dt = dv.Table;
    int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    dt.Rows[rowIndex]["FirstName"] = thenewfirstname;
    dt.Rows[rowIndex]["MI"] = thenewmi;
    dt.Rows[rowIndex]["LastName"] =thenewlastname;
    Session["My_DataTable"] = dv;
    //Reset the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    GridView1.DataSource = Session["My_DataTable"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

The underlying DataView/DataTable is changed correctly, but the GridView contains both the old row before the edit, and the new row after the edit (that is, it adds an additional row with the new edits!).

For example, if we have :

```
...
Sammy S Samerson 
...
```

and change it to `Sammy E Samerson` the gridview says :

```
...
Sammy S Samerson
Sammy E Samerson
...
```

How do I fix this, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You sure Sammy E didn't overwrite another entry? or is your total row count also increased?

Comment: I am sure no entry was overwritten, and the row count is increased by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of strange things were happening.

The gist of all of the Bad Things was the DataView - because things were being reordered, the index of the GridView, and the index of the DataTable in the DataView weren't matching up. The DataTable had to be looped through untill the correct just-edited record was found.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the row index of the editing row.  int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; you can directly use the e.RowIndex.

My Suggestion is to get the row by using any key field of the table.

for example

```
DataRow[] customerRow = 
dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Select("CustomerID = 'ALFKI'");

customerRow[0]["CompanyName"] = "Updated Company Name";
customerRow[0]["City"] = "Seattle";
```

You can get the row values by using the cell position. Or  use datakeynames
for example :

```
string courseid = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
```